# Android - NestedScrollView which contains ExpandableListView doesn't scroll when expanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-nestedscrollview

I have an `ExpandableListView` inside a `NestedScrollView` (yes I know, it is not good to have a scrolling view inside another scrolling view but I don't know what else to do, please do tell me if anybody knows a better approach).

The size of the content in `NestedScrollView` is still within the screen so it won't scroll, but when `ExpandableListView` is expanded, the content will leak outside the screen but the `NestedScrollView` still won't scroll.. Why is this so?

Here's my `NestedScrollView` layout :

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
        ... // About 3 of the LinearLayouts
        <ExpandableListView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: refer this link http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/expandable-listview-inside-scrollview/#sthash.6gtbdQ0F.dpbs

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use `NonScrollExpandableListView` you can achieve non-scroll property of any `Lisview` or `GridView` or `ExpandableListView` by overriding following method.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

So for using `NonScrollExpandableListView` you need to make one custom class.

```
public class NonScrollExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

And use it like.

```
<com.example.extraclasses.NonScrollExpandableListView 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Will this cause performance issue?? It worked btw but I'm concerned about the performance issue (had NestedScrollview parenting RecyclerView and oh damn, the memory usage.......)

Comment: Not at all. infect it is recommended to use this in cases like yours.

Comment: It worked well, but can I just use expandableListView.onMeasure() and not make new class? I am still new at making those kind of custom classes.. Oh and btw it is "in fact" not "infect" lol

Comment: hahah.. I'm bad at spellings.. That is me.. anyway.. you have to make separate class for that.. you can't use it that ways..

Comment: it is `override` method of `view` class. you can use it only if you are extending any view. and if you see I have done coding inside `onMeasure()`. so if you use it like you mentioned it will take default scroll. and won't give desire result.

Comment: how to setselectedgroup in expandablelistview??? As it is not scrolling when the group is expanded.

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava can you elaborate your problem more?

Comment: @vrundpurohit suppose there are 10 parent groups. And I want click on 8th, so I want  the expandablelistview to scroll and show all its child which is not happening.Otherwise this solution is awesome.

Comment: have you tried warping `NonScrollExpandableListView` inside `ScrollView`?

Comment: if you did that you probably able to do that. are you using `ScrollView` or 'NestedScrollView'?

Comment: Thanks Worked For me. will it work with ListView and Recycler View Too?

Comment: Yes for `ListVIew` and i don't Recommend for `RecyclerView`

Comment: How can I animate view while it expand using NonScrollExpandableListView?

Comment: thanks a lot! But in my case I have a coordinatorlayout and inside it is my nestedscrollview and inside that is my expandablelistview so, what's happening is that my expandablelistview isn't expanding to the fullest unless the keyboard opens, which is weird

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit How to do the same for ListView instead of ExpandableListView??Please help?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit for me it worked only after i changed Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2 to Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 21 . Why its so? Also it work's with ScrollView not with NestedScrollView.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Seems like this will not work correctly for 3 level or 4 level ExpandableListview. Any help ??

Comment: Tried this solution to add expandable list view and recycler view to nested scrollview. Works fine, to be able to scroll both lists as one, but when you tap on a expandable list view group, when child expands, it doesn't scroll to the child content.

Answer (score 8):

Add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to your ExpandalbleListView layout.

Answer (score 6):

The answer from [V-rund Puro-hit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605908/4958717) is what worked for me. But it took some modifications to work with Kotlin supporting API >19. So for the purpose of saving someone time, here it is:

Create a new class file `NonScrollExpandableListView`:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter
import android.widget.ExpandableListView


class NonScrollExpandableListView : ExpandableListView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    override fun setAdapter(adapter: ExpandableListAdapter?) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter)
    }

    override fun setOnChildClickListener(onChildClickListener: OnChildClickListener) {
        super.setOnChildClickListener(onChildClickListener)
    }

    override fun expandGroup(groupPos: Int) : Boolean {
        return super.expandGroup(groupPos)
    }

    override fun expandGroup(groupPos: Int, animate: Boolean) : Boolean {
        return super.expandGroup(groupPos, animate)
    }

    override fun isGroupExpanded(groupPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return super.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)
    }

    public override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE shr 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom)
        val params = layoutParams
        params.height = measuredHeight
    }
}
```

...and I use it like so:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <com.example.you.kotlinlistview.NonScrollExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandableCategories"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_new_feed"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Add new feed"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settings_button"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/logout_button"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_exit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Log Out"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

As a result, I can comfortably add buttons and other elements to `NavigationView` side drawer) and it all works nicely in one common `ScrollView`. Main usage here is when you need to combine multiple `ListView`s and `ExpandableListView`s inside the one common `ScrollView` which would take care of scrolling.

Comment: How to do the same for ListView instead of ExpandableListView??Please help?

Comment: @KJEjava48 In the exact same way, you just need to override `ListView` class, and you don't need to override all the `expand...` classes. You can post a new question if you think it's beneficial to have the code for exactly that case (if you do, don't forget to refer to this question).

Comment: ok thank you.Can u explain what does this means in ur code Integer.MAX_VALUE shr 2 ?? what here 2 stands for??

Comment: for me it worked only after i changed Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2 to Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 21 . Why its so? Also it work's with ScrollView not with NestedScrollView.

Comment: @KJEjava48 In Kotlin `shr` is the keyword for [shift right operation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/shr.html). Regarding the MeasureSpec it is good to start with [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#makeMeasureSpec(int,%20int)). But generally this allows the expandable list view to change height depending on its state (expanded groups), instead of having a fixed height and becoming scrollable.

Comment: when i make it to 21 or 22 list is scrolling otherwise not scrolling...

Comment: It should not be scrolling. That was the whole point. You want to make it non-scrolling so you can combine it with other views. Then you make the whole thing scrollable by putting all these views inside a one common ScrollView.

Comment: Seems like this will not work correctly for 3 level or 4 level ExpandableListview. Any help ??

Comment: Scrolling is not smooth.

Comment: @HirenPatel I think the smoothness of scrolling is something one solves with profiling. If the drawing of the list elements takes a significant amount of computation it causes skipped frames. This is an independent issue, different from grouping the elements in a single srollable view. Or is this solution causing a significant computation overhead for you?

Comment: super.onMeasure is throwing exception

Answer (score 3):

Use this method this will calculate the ExpendableListSize at run time.

```
 private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
                               int group) {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
        groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                        listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            }
        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    int height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
    if (height < 10)
        height = 200;
    params.height = height;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

An call this method in your setOnGroupClickListener.like below

```
mExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't use listview, gridview or expandable listview inside scrollview. If you wan't to use expandable listview inside scrollview then you have to give some fixed height to your expandable listview.

Comment: Oh I see, so it has to be a fixed height.. If I give a fixed height, for example 40 dp, would it take that much space even if it is expanded? And how do people make `ExpandableListView` inside another scrolling view? I've seen several apps like that..

Comment: @KevinMurvie By default android won't fully support one scrollable view inside another scrollable view. But we can do something and it can be done. But it will not be a perfect one. [For your reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/11554684#11554684)

Comment: Actually I've seen that and I've applied that (RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView).. But too bad it has performance issues and I do it with recyclerview.. So those apps actually doesn't play by the rules?

Comment: Exactly, we can do something and we can achieve that type of scrolling but it will have performance and scrolling issues.