# Expandable ListView inside Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, expandablelistview

I tried to have an **ExpandableListView** inside a **ScrollView** but I doesn't work and after having done some search seems to be impossible. 
The problem is that I didn't come up with a solution.
I need an expanded View inside a scroll View.
Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: ExpandableListView have scrollview inside it so actually you do not need to put it inside a ScrollView. If your items in expandablelistview are more than height of your expandablelistview, you will see that it can be scroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - NestedScrollView which contains ExpandableListView doesn't scroll when expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605545/android-nestedscrollview-which-contains-expandablelistview-doesnt-scroll-when)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need an ExpandableListView in a ScrollView.
You should add the views above the ExpandableListView as Header to the ExpandableListView, and add the views below the ExpandableListView as Footer to the ExpandableListView. Then all of them can scroll together.

Answer (score 0):

It would helps

```
    left_drawer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```