# How to make Android ExpandableListView not scrollable?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I can't figure it out how to make ExpandableListView not scrollable, always at full size and positioning at the bottom of the layout, but also maintain the ability to scroll the textView if it goes out of bounds. I know it is not recommended to have ListView in ScrollView. But how to achieve this? Now everything looks like this:

[image]

The layout:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Order description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:id="@+id/orderDescr"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:text="label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:indicatorLeft="?
    android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
    android:childDivider="#00000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/orderDescr"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605545/android-nestedscrollview-which-contains-expandablelistview-doesnt-scroll-when