# Scrolling in ExpandableListView with coordinator layout

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

My problem is scrolling in ExpandableListView with coordinator layout design.
 Toolbar works right and When it touched up, it gets hide, but ExpandableListView doesnt scroll

I need to use NestedScrollView because the layout_navigation_view is Common everywhere.

Take a look at the

[picture http://info-sys.persiangig.com/noScroll.gif](http://info-sys.persiangig.com/noScroll.gif)

My main code with Java AND My design code with XML is:

**ActivityMain.java**

```
public class ActivityMain   extends ActivityNavigationView {

           ArrayList<StructNote> group ; //StructNote public String id,title,icon; // StructNote = Filde Parametr
           ArrayList<ArrayList<StructNote>> child ;

           ActivityAdapter mAdapter; // class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 

           ExpandableListView exListView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ---> content_frame =>  layout_navigation_view.xml
        FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame); 
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, contentFrameLayout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);

        exListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exListView);

        //... Fill Group Child Adapter List
        //...Other CODE ...
    }
 }
```

**ActivityNavigationView.java**

```
public class ActivityNavigationView extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_navigation_view);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //...Other CODE ... Click menu and Open close NavigationView, Toolbar
    }
 }
```

**layout_navigation_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_tool_bar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_activity_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/exListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:transcriptMode="disabled"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:minHeight="130dp">
            </ExpandableListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Edit :**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/exListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:transcriptMode="disabled"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:minHeight="130dp">
            </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Toolbar works right and When it touched up, it gets hide, but `ExpandableListView` **doesnt scroll**

Yes it's because of `SwipeRefreshLayout` and using **[`SwipeRefreshLayout` inside of `NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface#AddSwipeWidget)**.

> Add the `SwipeRefreshLayout` Widget To add the swipe to refresh widget to
>   an existing app, add `SwipeRefreshLayout` **as the parent of a single
>   ListView or GridView**

**Solution:**

Place `SwipeRefreshLayout` outside of `NestedScrollView` in `layout_navigation_view.xml` first:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And remove `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: yes i know and that is right for ListvVew, GrideView and RecyclerView 
**but**
it doesnt work for ExpandableListView 
and i need to scroll **ExpandableListView **

Comment: `public class ExpandableListView 
extends ListView ` **It extends from ListView** and since you have added `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside of `NestedScrollView` this causes issue. And [`SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) is not what you need for scrolling.

Comment: "SwipeRefreshLayout" isnt important
it doesnt cause issue

Comment: Oh, i missed this one. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605908/4409113 It's because of (`ExpandableListView` & `NestedScrollView`) both are scrollable.