# Android: Scroll whole fragment with ListView inside

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following structure in my fragment layout file:

```
- ScrollView
  - ConstraintLayout
    - CardView
      - *some stuff here*
    - CardView
      - ListView
        - *list header*
        - *list items generated with a custom adapter*
```

If I remove the outer `ScrollView`, I can see the whole content of the `ListView`, and if it's bigger than the remaining space for the 2nd `CardView`, I can scroll it. The 1st `CardView` stays in place, but the content of the 2nd one is scrollable.

However, I would like to scroll the whole fragment. I would like the 2nd `CardView` to expand and contain the whole `ListView`, and if I scroll up or down, the 1st one moves as well.

I tried several combinations of height settings. No point of showing you my actual layout XML, because it's a mess. I would like a clean slate. Is it possible to achieve?

*EDIT:*

I know the `ListView` is a scroll container itself, but I think it's a pretty common need to scroll the whole thing, so I can't understand why it's so hard to make it work.

Comment: Maybe it will work if you replace the ScrollView with NestedScrollView.

Comment: @Arantik I have tried it. No luck.

Comment: @Arantik Turns out, `NestedScrollView` was part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after combining multiple answers, I have the solution that I needed.

## First

I needed to use a `NestedScrollView` instead of a regular `ScrollView`.

It solves the conflict between the two scroll containers (`ScrollView` and `ListView`).

*Reference: [Android: ScrollView vs NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773982/android-scrollview-vs-nestedscrollview)*

NOTE: My list content is dynamic, so it can be too short to fill the remaining space. I had to set `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `NestedScrollView`. If the list is longer than the remaining space, it will not cause any trouble.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- NOTE: constraints properties are missing from here for easier reading -->

            <!-- card content here -->

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- NOTE: constraints properties are missing from here for easier reading -->

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <!-- NOTE: this will change in step 3 -->

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

## Second

Following the steps above will make the `ListView` collapse to the height of its first item. To solve this, I needed to create a subclass from `ListView` and override its `onMeasure()` method, so it can calculate the proper height at runtime.

*Reference: [Android - NestedScrollView which contains ExpandableListView doesn't scroll when expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605545/android-nestedscrollview-which-contains-expandablelistview-doesnt-scroll-when)*

**NonScrollListView.java**

```
package my.package.name

import ...

public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {
    
    // NOTE: right click -> create constructors matching super

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

## Third

I needed to use my custom View instead of the regular `ListView` in my layout XML.

**layout.xml** excerpt

```
<my.package.name.NonScrollListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This way I managed to make it work. Both cards move together on scroll, even if I tap the `ListView` area.

I don't know whether it causes performance issues with really long lists, because mine contains a few dozen items at most, but I have no problem on a low end Galaxy A20e.