# how do I make my whole display to be scrollable

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview, android-nestedscrollview

I am making an App for my restaurant, there when the user enters the restaurant page, he or she will be able to see all the selectable Item here is the image below:

[image]

Here you can see that I have highlighted a portion and that portion is Expandable listView. The thing is that when I scroll the expandable list VIew I want the whole page to scroll up not just the Expandable List the whole page to be a scroll when I scroll in either direction.

here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".UI_Activity.RestaurantDetail">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantBackKey"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_key"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="13dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/RestaurantImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="RestaurantName"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" This shop is based on the real thing"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="Offers"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OfferAvailability"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="No Offers %"
                android:textColor="#9BA176"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Menu Item"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantItemList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me what changes to be made or which layout or is there any update That I have to do in my existing code?

What I want is that when I scroll the expandable list View I want the whole display to get scroll along with it.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by making a custom class for ExpandableListView. Where I have made some changes and finally I was able to achieve the result I was looking for either way thank you.

you can refer to this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605545/android-nestedscrollview-which-contains-expandablelistview-doesnt-scroll-when)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap the entire layout in a `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: What didn't work? Did you try any of [these workarounds](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01u8jr65vOMmgBT2kfr3Y791xXVbg%3A1598531948494&ei=bKlHX__KHZTY-wSB2a3wBQ&q=expandablelistview+nestedscrollview&oq=ExpandableListView+nested&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIABBDOgIIADoHCAAQFBCHAjoICAAQFhAKEB46BQghEKABUKIOWM8dYKYkaAFwAXgAgAFoiAHEBZIBAzYuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab)?

Comment: And when I use the NestedScrollView the Expandable list view gets disappeared! I mean it's no where to found in the layout!

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole layout inside a `ScrollView`, that will make everything scrollable.

Comment: if I put the whole layout inside ScrollView then the Expandable list view gets Wrapped height! even if I use match parent. I have tried that too